# Querying web app with java 6 bytecode on a tomcat running under Java 7

Tags: java, tomcat, java-7, java-6

I have following scenario.

My web app is in Java 6 bytecode and I deployed it on a tomcat which runs unders Java 7.
I can query the web app via an java api.

Now my question: Does is make sense to query the web app using java 6? Or does it only make sense to query using java 7 since tomcat is running under java 7?

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter and I don't see any advantages or disadvantages. What kind of API does your webapp expose? If it is a real API, the API shouldn't be bound to any programming language. Imagine having a REST interface, where you only use HTTP requests to get and post JSON messages. You can do that in any language, not just Java.

Or are you talking about a remote code invocation, e.g. using EJB? In that case you have to follow how the standards define invoking code of a Java 6 app.